# htaccess redirection on specific domain to specific path

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite, httpd

i am going to redirect my domain to specific path.

thing that i want is

```
admin.example.com to admin.example.com/admin
partner.example.com to partner.example.com/partner
```

I need this two function in one .htaccess file.
Thanks.

Comment: What should `admin.example.com/<something>` redirect to? Do you have any existing directives in your `.htaccess` file? What have you tried so far that is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `admin.example.com` and `partner.example.com` point to the same place on the filesystem, then in the document root try the following (mod_rewrite directives) at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(admin|partner)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^(admin|partner) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=302,L]
```

This will redirect just the two specific URLs as stated in your question, namely:

- `http://admin.example.com/` to `http://admin.example.com/admin`
- `http://partner.example.com/` to `http://partner.example.com/partner`

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) when you are sure it is working OK - if this is to be a permanent redirect. (302s are easier for testing, since they won't be cached by the browser.)